# Bananian python sqlite 3 ptoblem no such column:

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, raspbian

I really don know why but i try to run a program that used to work on my linux computer, and now a simple command does not work on bananian. I tried to run only the part who give an error. So I wrote a simple sql script again to understand where the error is from:

```
import sqlite3
conn2 = sqlite3.connect('datatest.db')  # start the data base
databa2 = conn2.cursor()

try:
    databa2.execute("CREATE TABLE datatest(date blob, rd blob)")
    if conn2:
        conn2.commit()
except:
    databa2.execute("DROP TABLE datatest ")
    databa2.execute("CREATE TABLE datatest (date blob, rd blob)")
    if conn2:
        conn2.commit()
a=1
b=2
print (b)
databa2.execute("INSERT INTO datatest VALUES (?,?)", (a,b))
databa2.execute("INSERT INTO datatest VALUES (?,?)", (b,a))
databa2.execute("INSERT INTO datatest VALUES (?,?)", (a,a))
if conn2:
    conn2.commit()

for row in conn2.execute("SELECT date , rd "):
    print(row)
if conn2:
    conn2.commit()
```

I also tried to just had random value (not just a,b...). And then when I try to print it it does not work and give me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/media/datatest.py", line
>   25, in 
>       for row in conn2.execute("SELECT date , rd "): OperationalError: no such column: date

I also looked at the database in DB browser, and the columns exist but are empty. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I changed the structure following a tutorial, and now it works, I don't really understand why it used to work before and why I had to change. But whatever now it works with this.

```
 import sqlite3
    conn2 = sqlite3.connect('datatest.db')  # start the data base
    databa2 = conn2.cursor()

try:
    databa2.execute("CREATE TABLE datatest(date INT,ID INT)")

except:
    databa2.execute("DROP TABLE datatest ")
    databa2.execute("CREATE TABLE datatest (date INT, ID INT)")


databa2.execute("INSERT INTO datatest (date, ID) VALUES (?,?)",(5, 10))
databa2.execute("INSERT INTO datatest (date, ID) VALUES (?,?)",(2, 98))
databa2.execute("INSERT INTO datatest (date, ID) VALUES (?,?)",(5, 47))
if conn2:
    conn2.commit()

for row in conn2.execute("SELECT (date) from datatest "):
    print(row)
if conn2:
    conn2.commit()
```